# While Loop Counter Not Incrementing

Tags: c++, while-loop

I set a count variable = 1, then increment by 1 inside the loop.  In the loop, the count does increment (cout confirms this), but it seems that the count resets itself with each iteration of the loop.  As a result, count is always ==2 and the if statement will never execute because count !=3.  How do I increment the count instead of resetting it to 1 each time?

```
int main()
{
long numberOfPeople;
int  count = 1;

cout << "Enter the current population: ";
cin >> numberOfPeople;

while (numberOfPeople < 1)
{
    count++;
    cout << "count: " << count << "\n";
    cout << "Invalid Entry. Number must be greater than 1. Try again." << "\n" ;
    if (count > 3)
    {
        cout << "Too many invalid entries. Program terminated. ";
        return 0;
    }
    return main();
    } 
}
```

Comment: You're not allowed to call `main()` recursively in C++. Is that really what you wanted to do?

Comment: I called main() because I want to return to the original cout line while count != 3. I now know that is incorrect

Comment: @user8773453 I suspect that you've heard about loops.

Comment: The program doesn't make much sense but I think you want to take out return main(); because that goes back to the entry point. Maybe replace return main(); with return count; ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the line:

```
return main();
```

This is restarting the program by calling `main()` again. So instead of returning to the beginning of the `while` loop with the incremented `count` variable, you go back to the `int count = 1;` statement that resets it. Calling `main()` recursively is actually undefined behavior in C++, although it's allowed in C and many C++ compilers will compile it similarly.

I'm not sure why you have that statement in there, just get rid of it.

Another problem is that `numberOfPeople` never changes during the loop. You need to put:

```
cin >> numberOfPeople;
```

at the bottom of the `while` loop.

```
while (numberOfPeople < 1)
{
    count++;
    cout << "count: " << count << "\n";
    if (count > 3)
    {
        cout << "Too many invalid entries. Program terminated. ";
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "Invalid Entry. Number must be greater than 1. Try again." << "\n";
    cin >> numberOfPeople;
}
```

Comment: Might want to note that, in C++, calling `main()` is not allowed anyway  (even if not all compilers enforce that).

Comment: true, but comments are more transitory.